# lubridate: how to convert difftime to millisecond units (and plot it)?

Tags: r, datetime, ggplot2, lubridate

Consider the following example

```
time = c('2013-01-03 22:04:21.549', '2013-01-03 22:04:21.549', '2013-01-03 22:04:21.559', '2013-01-03 22:04:23.559' )
ref = c('2013-01-03 22:04:20', '2013-01-03 22:04:20', '2013-01-03 22:04:20', '2013-01-03 22:04:20')
value = c(1,2,3,4)


data <- data_frame(time, ref, value)
data <-data %>%  mutate(time = ymd_hms(time),
                        ref = ymd_hms(ref),
                        difftime = time - ref)

# A tibble: 4 × 4
                 time                 ref value   difftime
               <dttm>              <dttm> <dbl>     <time>
1 2013-01-03 22:04:21 2013-01-03 22:04:20     1 1.549 secs
2 2013-01-03 22:04:21 2013-01-03 22:04:20     2 1.549 secs
3 2013-01-03 22:04:21 2013-01-03 22:04:20     3 1.559 secs
4 2013-01-03 22:04:23 2013-01-03 22:04:20     4 3.559 secs
```

I would like to get a scatterplot of `value` and `difftime` where the units of `difftime` are in **milliseconds**.

I dont know how to do that. The best I could do is the following:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = value, y = difftime )) + geom_point() 

Don't know how to automatically pick scale for object of type difftime. Defaulting to continuous.
```

[image]

but that keeps the seconds representation.

Any ideas? 
Thanks!!

Comment: Is your question how to convert 1s to 1000 ms?

Comment: you can always do `difftime = difftime * 1000` but it will show up as `1000 seconds` instead of  `1000 milliseconds`

Comment: Warning: try to avoid giving your objects the same name as functions. Both `data` and `difftime` are functions in R.

Comment: yes thank you. This is just for this example.

Comment: An object of class difftime can take values in `"secs", "mins", "hours", "days", "weeks"`; see also `?difftime`. What about converting to numeric (e.g: `dat$difference  <- as.numeric(dat$difference) * 1000`) and then plot?

Comment: yeah but maybe `lubridate` can understand millisecond units? it is not clear at all by looking at the documentation. that will allow consistent operations between difftimes with different units

Comment: From `?difftime`: "The `as.double` method returns the numeric value expressed in the specified units". There are also two examples using `as.numeric`. Please do some basic research before posting.

Comment: @Henrik thanks I missed that. Do you mind posting your solution then?

Comment: the answer is actually far from being obvious. I think the downvoters should reconsider their vote. ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `attributes` function to modify the units of `difftime` object:

```
time = c('2013-01-03 22:04:21.549', '2013-01-03 22:04:21.549', '2013-01-03 22:04:21.559', '2013-01-03 22:04:23.559' )
ref = c('2013-01-03 22:04:20', '2013-01-03 22:04:20', '2013-01-03 22:04:20', '2013-01-03 22:04:20')
value = c(1,2,3,4)


library("dplyr")
library("ggplot2")
library("lubridate")

DF <- data.frame(time, ref, value)
DF <- DF %>%  mutate(time = ymd_hms(time),
                        ref = ymd_hms(ref),
                        delta_time_secs = time - ref)

attributes(DF$delta_time_secs)
#
#$units
#[1] "secs"
#
#$class
#[1] "difftime"
```

Using `attributes` to change units:

```
DF <- DF %>%  mutate(delta_time_msecs = (time - ref)*1000)

attributes(DF$delta_time_msecs)$units="milliseconds"

attributes(DF$delta_time_msecs)
#$units
#[1] "milliseconds"
#
#$class
#[1] "difftime



DF
#                 time                 ref value delta_time_secs  delta_time_msecs
#1 2013-01-03 22:04:21 2013-01-03 22:04:20     1      1.549 secs 1549 milliseconds
#2 2013-01-03 22:04:21 2013-01-03 22:04:20     2      1.549 secs 1549 milliseconds
#3 2013-01-03 22:04:21 2013-01-03 22:04:20     3      1.559 secs 1559 milliseconds
#4 2013-01-03 22:04:23 2013-01-03 22:04:20     4      3.559 secs 3559 milliseconds



ggplot(DF, aes(x = value, y = as.numeric(delta_time_msecs))) + geom_point() + ylab("Time in milliseconds")
```

[image]

Comment: The object oriented nature of R comes to light with interesting problem like yours :)

Comment: That's unnecessarily complicated, IMHO. Why don't you just do `ggplot(DF, aes(x = value, y = as.numeric(delta_time_secs) * 1000)) + ...` without mutating `DF` as Jaap had suggested?

Comment: maybe because  i dont wanna see 1000 seconds in my dataframe. its just cleaner like that dont u think